# TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to loop through my array and I am facing the below error:
TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

I am highlighting my Search value using the below getHighlightedText function. My code:

```
getHighlightedText = text => {
    const {value} = this.props;

    if (value == "" || value == null || value == 0) {
        return <Text> {text} </Text>
    } else {
        const words = value.split(/\s+/g).filter(word => word.length);
        const pattern = words.join('|');
        const re = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi')
        const children = [];
        let before, highlighted, match, pos = 0;

        const matches = text.match(re);
        for (match of matches) { // guess this the error location
            match = re.exec(text)
            if (pos < match.index) {
                before = text.substring(pos, match.index);
                if (before.length) {
                    children.push(before)
                }
            }
            highlighted = <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'coral'}}>{match[0]} </Text>
            children.push(highlighted);
            pos = match.index + match[0].length;
        }
        if (pos < text.length) {
            const last = text.substring(pos);
            children.push(last);
        }
        return <Text>{children} </Text>
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?? Any ideasss????

Comment: This code doesn't seem C. Please use only proper tags.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to not spam with unrelated tags, as that will make less people interested in helping you. And remember that Java and Javascript are two *very* different languages!

Comment: removed the C and java tag.

Comment: Thank you for the solution MikeCAT and Some programmer dude.

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure that `text.match(re)` really find any matches? Reading the error it seems like `text.match(re)` returns `null`. Have you tried to debug your code? Stepping through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values? Is the `pattern` really what you expect it to be? Is the `text` what you expect it to be?

Comment: yes text.match(re) does find a match. My Search value is getting highlighted in my List. But it's very unstable. The error is not thrown immediately. I can search for a couple of times and then the error pops up.

Comment: Well it seems like it doesn't *always* find a match.  I recommend that you add some check for `matches` being `null`, and then print or log the values of all relevant variables. That way you should hopefully come to some insight when and where the problem could emanate from.

Comment: @some programmer dude you were correct I just added a condition and the error is resolved :) but I am facing one more issue with escaping special characters. If I type * or ? Or / any special character it throws a invalid reflex expression nothing to repeat!!!! Trying to add it to pattern in the above code. Not working!!!

Comment: \\* \? \/ or [*] [?]  https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping  https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html